# Problema con NONE en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Me ha surgido un problema realizando un proyecto en Python3.
Después de crear una variable e intentar introducirla en un fichero aparte llamado Almacen.txt, en vez de introducirme el valor de la variable me introduce NONE, y como entenderán es bastante frustrante la verdad.
A continuación les muestro el código:

```
import string as s 
from random import *
import io 
import time as tm

print("Entre que valores quieres que esté tu contraseña (x=minimo    Y=maximo): ")

x = int(input("x= "))
y = int(input("y= "))
while True:
    def generador(x, y):
        tm.sleep(0.5)
        ch = s.ascii_letters + s.digits + s.punctuation
        password = "".join(choice(ch) for i in
        range(randint(x, y)))
        print(password)
    pasword = generador(x, y)
    password = str(pasword)




    f = io.open("Almacen.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n\n" + str(password))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Tu funcion `generador` no retorna nada, por lo que retorna `None`. Añadele un `return password`. El print no es un return.

Comment: El programa me imprime la contraseña en pantalla, eso está bien, el problema es que a la hora de introducir ese mismo valor en el otro archivo me devuelve None.

Comment: Que sí, tu haz el cambio que te digo :-) Si quieres escribo una respuesta para explicarlo mejor

Comment: Tenías razón, mil gracias, de verdad

Answer (score 1):

Como ya indiqué en un comentario el problema es que la función `generador()` no tenía ninguna instrucción `return`. Cuando ocurre esto, la función retorna en realidad `None`.

Por tanto cuando hacías `pasword = generador(x, y)` el resultado que obtenías en `pasword` era `None`, y al convertirlo a cadena, `"None"`.

La solución es obviamente añadir un `return password` en la función `generador()`.

Es un error frecuente entre quienes empiezan a programar el hacer que las funciones **impriman** cosas en lugar de **retornarlas**. Imprimirlas puede estar bien para depuración, para ver que la función está calculando correctamente un valor, pero si quieres poder usar ese valor fuera de la función lo que hay que hacer es *retornarlo*.

De hecho, las funciones no deberían imprimir nada, sino retornar el resultado. Si quieres ver por pantalla ese resultado quien debería imprimirlo es quien ha llamado a la función, y no la función. Por tanto tu código sería más correcto así:

```
import string as s 
from random import randint
import io 
import time as tm

print("Entre que valores quieres que esté tu contraseña (x=minimo    Y=maximo): ")

x = int(input("x= "))
y = int(input("y= "))
while True:
    def generador(x, y):
        tm.sleep(0.5)
        ch = s.ascii_letters + s.digits + s.punctuation
        password = "".join(choice(ch) for i in
        range(randint(x, y)))
        return password   # <-- Aqui no imprimimos, retornamos el resultado

    password = generador(x, y)
    print("Contraseña generada:", password)  # <-- Aqui si

    f = io.open("Almacen.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n\n" +password)
    f.close()
```

He aprovechado para corregir el `import *`, que se desaconseja, cambiándolo por el import de exactamente la función que necesitas, y también he quitado las conversiones a `str()` de la `password`, pues lo que retorna la función ya es una cadena.

Aparte de eso, me han llamado la atención un par de cosas en tu código:

- ¿Por qué importas `io`? Puedes abrir un fichero directamente con `open()` sin importar ningún módulo
- ¿Por qué el bucle infinito? Realmente quieres que genere contraseñas sin fin y te las añada a un fichero? ¡Si lo dejas un rato acabará por llenarte el disco!